# What category of toposes is monadic over the 2-category of groupoids?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, monads, groupoids

Excuse my lack of understanding of monadicity, but I have been looking at toposes and monads.  I see [Lambek showed](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0066895) that the category of Toposes are monadic over the category of categories.  I see the 2-category of groupoids as possibly another candidate for which there may be a category of toposes that are monadic over it.  Is this the case?

A question has been asked about the 2-morphisms in my category of toposes that I think is monadic over the 2-category of groupoids.  From my limited understanding, the 2-category of toposes will have functors as morphisms.  The 2-morphisms would thus be natural transformations.  I have limited understanding of functors between toposes, knowing only one special kind which is the geometric morphism.  This means I have even less insight as to what the two morphisms would be.  Perhaps natural transformations of geometric morphisms?  I have to leave this question open in the sense that I am looking for any 2-category of toposes that is monadic over the 2-cat of groupoids.  Does this mean there are many 2-cats of toposes that will be monadic?

**The background as to why I am asking this**:
It has been asked a few times what my intuition is for asking this question.  Unfortunately, like most times I ask a broad question like this, my intuitions are unclear and might be from some physical intuition or vague maths.  This is mainly coming from the work I am doing to find polynomial monads for different types of containers.  In particular, the multi-set monad [is only polynomial on the 2-category of groupoids](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1571066113000029/1-s2.0-S1571066113000029-main.pdf?_tid=4ee3aadc-2146-4a48-a686-e067d0fd6d73&acdnat=1551119856_62385641cd81d9bd229a79f058d89eac).

Why do I care about this?  This comes from physics.  I am [working on a branch of physics](https://www.researchgate.net/project/Foundations-of-Physics-and-Science-Data-and-Theories) where data (not information), like lists, multisets(bags), trees, are at the foundation alongside the experiments which produce them.

We have seen physics taken apart to probe our logical frameworks due to Isham and Doering.  They were looking at picking a topos, other than SET, that suited modern physics, being more from a quantum origin.  I am also interested in finding a topos.  To that end, I asked if the 2-cat of groupoids itself is a topos.  Then I did a quick search and found Lambek's paper and then was interested in a Topos that was monadic over 2-groupoids.

So, multisets are very important data structures for physics, and they are only polynomial on the 2-cat of groupoids.  The polynomial nature is required for us to have a [theory of Containers that encapsulates them](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/polynomial+functor).  Given that I seem to be restricting myself to groupoids, I began to wonder where my topos might be.  Spivak has recently been writing about the [topos of sheaves over the interval domain](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10258.pdf).  His work uses a domain of intervals to mimic a temporal background.  My work sheds the idea of a background and instead focuses just on what happens in a lab, and how this relates to the systems the lab is trying to probe (think telescopes and distant galaxies).  Since I seem to be stuck with the 2-cat of groupoids as a kind of interface to systems, naturally I am wondering where my topos is.

Comment: What are the 2-arrows in your 2-category of toposes?

Comment: If the category of topoi is to be monadic over the category of groupoids, then in particular there will have to be a forgetful functor from the former category to the latter. I don't see a plausible candidate for such a functor. What underlying-groupoid functor do you have in mind? (Pardon me for omitting all the 2's that should precede words like "category" and "functor" in this situation.)

Comment: Why do you say you “see the 2-category of groupoids as another candidate for which there may be a category of toposes that is monadic over it”?  If you have some intuition behind this hope, please explain it a bit — without some idea of what 1-cells and 2-cells you’re looking for, or what forgetful functor to groupoids you’re imagining, the question is hopelessly ill-posed.  And asking for “the largest 2-category of toposes that’s monadic over groupoids” makes no sense; it’s like asking for the “largest ring of polynomials that’s well-ordered”, or something.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, I think everyone can see that there is very little intuition here.  My hope was that it might be straightforward.  It is not.  All these questions about constraining either the 2-morphisms, or cells, or the forgetful functor just makes me think that there are many possible categories of toposes that are monadic over the 2-category of groupoids.  If that is the case, then someone should say why or why not.  Should the question be closed?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine one intuition is that the 2cat of groupoids is a cat of cats.  So it is similar to CAT, just constrained.  I thought it would lead to a constraint on the cats of toposes that would be monadic over it.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks for taking a look at this question.  Excuse my frustration. I have wandered into something that I love to hear about but have very little knowledge of.

Comment: I think everyone answering you is probably under the impression that *no* nontrivial categories of toposes could possibly be monadic over groupoids.  I certainly can't think of any way such a category could be.  Remember that when a category $C$ is monadic over $D$, that means the objects of $C$ are objects of $D$ equipped with "extra structure" in some way.  But a topos is not a groupoid with structure; it is a *category* with structure.  Yes, of course a groupoid is a particular kind of category, but the underlying category of a nontrivial topos is never a groupoid.

Comment: @MikeShulman excellent, ok. thank you.  So the takeway is that when someone posts a question like this, it is sort of assumed that they might really know a good answer or have a path to an answer?  Then everyone is waiting to see what I might be thinking in the hopes that I may have something new to add.  My questions are often of the type "anything that might fit, please tell me about it".  I try to post to Math.Stack when I really feel that I am asking that kind of question.  In this case, I thought it was more clear.

Comment: @MikeShulman This is a shot in the dark, but could you have a category of classifying toposes for a category of localic groupoids?  Could this be a direction for finding some category of toposes monadic over some category of groupoids?  Maybe I want to further constrain my groupoids as well as my toposes.

Comment: The point of my question is that all 2-arrows in $\mathbf{Gpd}$ are invertible, so I don't see how one gets the non-invertible 2-arrows between geometric morphisms. Conversely, the forgetful functor to $\mathbf{Gpd}$ must invert all the 2-arrows, if they are not already all invertible.

Comment: @BenSprott I would say the takeaway is that when someone asks a question like this, people who think it is very unlikely to be true will sometimes express that feeling by suggesting to the asker some investigations they could do on their own that might leave them with the same feeling.  Of course the asker is not expected to know the answer, but I would say there's some expectation that they've thought a little about the question, and perhaps that they have some reason to believe that it *might* be true.

Comment: It might also help if you explained your motivation.  There are innumerable questions one might ask of the form "is X monadic over Y?".  Are topological spaces monadic over abelian groups?  Are commutative rings monadic over symmetric spectra?  For most of them the answer is probably no.  What is it that leads you to ask whether toposes are monadic over groupoids?  Most interesting questions about monadicity (which have a chance of being true) only arise once you already have a forgetful functor in mind, which is part of why everyone was asking you what forgetful functor you have in mind.